# Return different value when querying dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am pulling from a dictionary in Python. I have it setup like this:

```
entries = [
    {'website': 'yahoo','username': 'jblumberg','password': 'sdkljfhwe'},
    {'website': 'google','username': 'jblumberg1','password': 'CoIushujSetu'}
    ]
```

I am asking the user to give me a website so I can return the password as so:

```
def lookup_password(website):

    if website in entries.keys():
        encrypted_password = entries[website]

    return password_encrypt(encrypted_password, -encryption_key)

    pass
```

However that won't give me what I want. How do I set it up to give me the password value for the provided website?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `entries = {
    ['website': 'yahoo','username': 'jblumberg','password': 'sdkljfhwe'],
    ['website': 'google','username': 'jblumberg1','password': 'CoIushujSetu']
    }`? Think you messed up with brackets.

Comment: `entries.keys()` is incorrect. entries is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. As I continue I will play around with creating a dictionary of lists or using the website in front of the dictionary. For now Luke's lookup function was what I was initially looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def lookup_password(website):
    for entry in entries:
        if entry['website'] == website:
            return entry['password']
```

Output:

```
In[2]: lookup_password('google')
Out[2]: 'CoIushujSetu'
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's restructure your dict like this so that it's a dict with each key as a website, like it seems you treat it in your code:

```
entries = {
    'yahoo': {'username': 'jblumberg', 'password': 'sdkljfhwe'},
    'google': {'username': 'jblumberg1', 'passwprd': 'CoIushujSetu'}
}
```

Now a couple of changes to your original code gets us to what should be working:

```
if website in entries:
    encrypted_password = entries[website]['password']
```

I should note that `website in entries` and `website in entries.keys()` do the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiples small problems in your conception of your data :

First entries is a list. Therefore you won't be able to call ".keys()"

Also when using

```
encrypted_password = entries[website]
```

this will store the whole dictionnary. Meaning that you would then be able to access the password via ['password']

```
encrypted_password = entries[website]['password']
```

To resume : if you change you data to look like this

```
entries = {
'yahoo':{
    'username': 'jblumberg','password': 'sdkljfhwe'
},
'google':{
    'username': 'jblumberg1','password': 'CoIushujSetu'
},
}
def lookup_password(website):
    if website in entries:
        encrypted_password = entries[website]['password']
        return password_encrypt(encrypted_password, -encryption_key)

    pass
```

But if you keep the same data, it will have to look like this:

```
def lookup_password(website):
    for record in entries:
        if record['website'] == website:
            encrypted_password = record['website']
            return password_encrypt(encrypted_password, -encryption_key)

    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another dictionary:

```
entries = [
    {'yahoo':{'username': 'jblumberg','password': 'sdkljfhwe'},
    {'google':{'username': 'jblumberg1','password': 'CoIushujSetu'}
]
```

Then the following would happen:

```
>> website = 'yahoo'
>> entries[website]
>> {'username': 'jblumberg','password': 'sdkljfhwe'}
```

so if you wanted the password:

```
>> entires[website]['password']
>> 'sdkljfhwe'
```